# Can't load texture atlas in Swift playground?

Tags: swift, swift3, swift-playground, sktextureatlas

Alright, in the past I have loaded a SKTextureAtlas into my class simply by typing its name, however now in Swift playgrounds I have tried adding several extensions (.atlas, .spriteatlas, no extension..) and everything else, however I am getting the error:

```
Texture Atlas 'testAtlas' cannot be found.
```

This is how I am getting this:

```
override init(texture: SKTexture!, color: NSColor!, size: CGSize) {
        super.init(texture: texture, color: color, size: size)

        atlas = SKTextureAtlas(named: "testAtlas")
        print(atlas.textureNames) //to test if got it
    }
```

Im thinking this is a problem with their being no target in a playground however I have put it into my resources folder and it should be able to recognize the atlas:

[image]

How can I get a texture atlas in playgrounds with Swift 3?

Comment: 1 year has passed but this is not solved!

Comment: Does a solution exist to this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the name of your folder to `testAtlas.atlas`

Comment: Please edit your answer to explain why and how it solves the question.